# Reducer starts before mapper has finished

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am running a Map Reduce Program. However I am getting similar output even though I am running it with only mapper or both with mapper and reducer.

After this it never completes.It hangs up there on.

I am not getting why reducer is getting started before mapper has finished 100%? What might be potential problems?

Output:

```
Map 10% Reduce 0%
Map 19% Reduce 0%
Map 21% Reduce 0%
Map 39% Reduce 0%
Map 49% Reduce 0%
Map 63% Reduce 0% 
Map 67% Reduce 0% 
Map 68% Reduce 0% 
Map 68% Reduce 22%
Map 69% Reduce 22%
```

Here is a mapper code:

```
public class EntityCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  static String total_record="";

  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable baseAddress, Text line, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Text entity=new Text();
    IntWritable one=new IntWritable(1);

    total_record=total_record.concat(line.toString());
    String[] fields=total_record.split("::");
    if(fields.length==24)
    {
        entity.set(fields[22].trim());          
        context.write(entity,one);
        total_record="";
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Why must the reduce process wait for **all** the mappings to complete? Reduce can be started as soon as there is enough data for it to start - e.g. two nodes completed their map job.

Comment: @user3707125 not really, it cannot start *reducing* until **all** mappers have finished. Untl then, it can only start *shuffling*, i.e., getting the output of the mappers that have finished.

Comment: What do you mean "I am getting similar output even though I am running it with only mapper or both with mapper and reducer" ?

Comment: @vefthym I mean that I set only mapper class in one case and in another case I set both mapper and reducer classes to a job configuration

Comment: @GauravGandhi that's because, if you specify no reducer, the identityReducer is used by default. If you don't want a reducer, set the number of reduce tasks to zero `conf.setNumReduceTasks(0);`

Answer (score 7):

The reduce phase has 3 steps: shuffle, sort, reduce. Shuffle is where the data is collected by the reducer from each mapper. This can happen while mappers are generating data since it is only a data transfer. On the other hand, sort and reduce can only start once all the mappers are done. You can tell which one MapReduce is doing by looking at the reducer completion percentage: 0-33% means its doing shuffle, 34-66% is sort, 67%-100% is reduce. This is why your reducers will sometimes seem "stuck" at 33%-- it's waiting for mappers to finish.

Answer (score 6):

This is controlled by `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` setting.  By default, reduces will be scheduled once 5% of the maps are complete.  This typically only starts the copy phase of the reducer.  Once the maps are complete, each reducer will then sort and reduce the input (output from the mappers).

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of config "mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps" as high as possible(we generally follow a practice to set it around 0.96 to 0.98). This will let the mapper finish 96% to 98% and then reducer will be started.

This will also avoid the holding of resource by reducer when the mapper is still running.